Why does my texture baking keep stopping and not getting anywhere near the end?
I am trying to bake a albedo/normal/rough map for a counter strike weapon finish and Everytime I click bake it goes for maybe a minute then just stops and gives either a black map or a glitchy looking map



You can use the Windows snip tool or screenshot feature within Blender Window > Save Screenshot to capture your screen. Don't take photos of your monitor.
